# Re-arranging the position of values in a list in python without writing repetitive, tedious code

Tags: python

So i have made a list and i am trying to switch the positions of values in my list without writing the long code that i have commented out:

```
list = [23,5,3,1,34,5]
print(list)

#list[0],list[5] = list[5],list[0]

l = len(list)
for i in range( 1 // 2 ):
    list[i],list[l-i-1] = list[l-i-1],list[i]
print(list)
```

when i run my code it prints the same list in the same order. How can i code it in a way that the values are switched without writing long tedious code?

Comment: on what base you are re arranging the position of values , can you give expected output ?

Comment: `1//2` is zero, so that range is empty, and nothing in the loop gets done. Show us what output you want from that input list. And please don't use `list` as a variable name, that shadows the built-in `list` type.

Comment: I *think* you simply want to reverse your list. There's a very easy way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in range( 1 // 2 ):` <-- that is the number `1`, not the letter `l`. You need to use more clear names for your variables. You actually don't need to use `l` in your indexing because `list[-x] == list[len(list) - x]` for all `1 <= x <= len(list)`.

```
lst = [23,5,3,1,34,5]

for index in range( len(lst) // 2 ):
    lst[index], lst[-index-1] = lst[-index-1], lst[index]
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

`FHTMichell`'s answer fixes your code, but if you want to just reverse the list, there are two easier methods:

```
lst[::-1]
```

or:

```
lst.reverse()
```

which both give:

```
[5, 34, 1, 3, 5, 23]
```

---

**why?**

The `.reverse` method is just built-in to the `list` object and the `[::-1]` slice takes advantage of the slice syntax:

```
[start : stop : step]
```

so if we leave `start` and `stop` to take their defaults (ends of the list) and set `step` to `-1`, then we get the list in reverse!